# Issue in installing ICC from intel oneapi basetoolkit issue with license file

Tags: centos, icc, intel-oneapi

We are trying to build ORAN- ODU-Low library (https://docs.o-ran-sc.org/projects/o-ran-sc-o-du-phy/en/latest/build_prerequisite.html).

We have downloaded and built DPDK ,

```
#wget http://static.dpdk.org/rel/dpdk-18.08.tar.x
#tar -xf dpdk-18.08.tar.xz
#export RTE_TARGET=x86_64-native-linuxapp-icc
#export RTE_SDK=Intallation_DIR/dpdk-18.08
```

build DPDK:

```
#./usertools/dpdk-setup.sh
select [39] x86_64-native-linuxapp-icc
exit [62] Exit Script
'''
```

DPDK built successfully.

While building fapi library from odu, we see below errors:

```
In file included from /home/user/odu-low/phy/fapi_5g/source/include/nr5g_fapi_dpdk.h:28:0,from /home/user/odu-low/phy/fapi_5g/source/include/nr5g_fapi_args.h:23,from /home/user/odu-low/phy/fapi_5g/source/nr5g_fapi.c:32:
/home/user/odu-low/dpdk-18.08/include/dpdk/rte_memcpy.h:797:2: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘_mm_storeu_si128’ MOVEUNALIGNED_LEFT47(dst, src, n, srcofs);
    

In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/xmmintrin.h:1246:0,
from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/x86intrin.h:34,from /home/user/odu-low/dpdk-18.08/include/dpdk/rte_vect.h:29, from /home/user/odu-low/dpdk-18.08/include/dpdk/rte_memcpy.h:17, from /home/user/odu-low/phy/fapi_5g/source/include/nr5g_fapi_dpdk.h:28, from /home/user/odu-low/phy/fapi_5g/source/include/nr5g_fapi_args.h:23, from /home/user/odu-low/phy/fapi_5g/source/nr5g_fapi.c:32:
\/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/emmintrin.h:700:1: note: expected ‘__m128i’ but argument is of type ‘int’
    _mm_storeu_si128 (__m128i *__P, __m128i __B)
```

We are building it on CentOS 7 - 3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64 gcc version used: 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC)

Comment: Was that really the *only* error message?  Something having type `int` instead of `__m128i` could be due to an implicit declaration for something, e.g. trying to use a function that wasn't declared because of an old compiler (old system GCC headers).

Comment: Wrt gcc not icc

Comment: @SindhuPitta as per the error logs `nr5g_fapi.c` having an issue with the second argument. As per your comment above this is for GCC and Not ICC. Can you please update the error with respect to ICC?

Comment: Wrt icc it is requesting for a license file and we are following the below link https://docs.o-ran-sc.org/projects/o-ran-sc-o-du-phy/en/latest/build_prerequisite.html#install-icc

Answer (score 0):

Intel compiler icc was previously available as a part of intel system studio and required a license. The documentation on installing icc you refer  seems to on O-RAN docs seems to be written during this period. Intel system studio now has been replaced by Intel oneAPI toolkits

Currently intel compilers(eg icc) are available for free without any license as a part of intel oneAPI HPC toolkit. You could easily download the toolkit for free by visiting the below link, and start using icc without issues.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit-download.html

If you still need to download the older versions of icc you could try out by visiting the below link.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/download-documentation-intel-system-studio-current-previous.html